# Drag and drop to point in canvas image using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, ui-testing

For my automated tests I am required to drag and drop an icon onto an image as part of the test, I have seen its possible to drag and drop from point A to point B. But in this case I dont have a point B.

The html for the image is shown as:

[image]

Im wondering is it possible to find a point within this image and drag my icon to this point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each element has a .location property of type dict. For example:

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath")
location = e.location
print(location)
```

Which gives you:

```
{'y': 114, 'x': 267}
```

You can use this coordinates to find the point where to drop the icon. Or to be more robust you can also get the .size attribute (which gives you for example {'width': 100, 'height': 200}) use this dict to find the center of the image and drop the icon to the center of the image.